CiviRules - complex delays?
I'm trying to implement an email newsletter with CiviRules.  I want emails for this newsletter to only go out on Saturday or Sunday between 8 am and 10 am.  There's a long series of emails in this chain.
What I'm doing right now is triggering the CiviRule when the user is added to a group, then the CiviRule actions are all "Send Email with delay of X days", where X is 7, 14, 21, etc. for each email in the series.
I'm struggling to figure out how to create a delay action that can get the sequence of "Send Email" actions into the sending window I want.  For two reasons:

I don't see a CiviRule action that can be limited to certain day/time windows like this.
Every delay seems to be triggered off the original CiviRule event, not off the prior action.  So I can't do something like have the first action be "wait until Saturday" and then all other actions be "Delay by 7 days" because the actions don't cascade like that.
I don't see a way to have multiple delays on an action.  Because then you could do "Day of week" option AND "delay by X days" option together.  As it stands, "Day of week" option with multiple email actions will fire all the emails on the same day because you can't use the "delay by X days" to sequence them.

Is anyone else doing this successfully?
Thank you!

For an alternative (not CiviRules) approach to that problem, take a look at the Chassé extension  That will send your series of emails and one of its listed features is:

You can limit automatic processing to certain times (or days or
day-of-month) e.g. to only email people in the evening.


Yes, I love love love Chasse.  Unfortunately its major limitation is it only allows a person to be part of one email series at a time.  That does not work for us and we were not able to convince the author to change the design to accommodate multiple journeys even with funding.  For any organization that is sure they will only have a person on one email series at once, Chasse is by far the best answer.

This might be do-able by using two groups:
Intake Group - this is the group the user is joined to when they sign up for the newsletter on your web site.
Newsletter Group - this group is used to trigger newsletters to go out.
Using CiviRules, you can trigger on users being added to Intake Group.

The first action might send them an immediate welcome email
The second action is to add them to Newsletter Group, with a delay of "Day of week", "Every week", "Saturday".
The final action removes the person from Intake Group

NOW you have a situation where users are always added to Newsletter Group at the designated day/time.  So in Newsletter Group you can fire off emails using the delays of X days.
It's cumbersome though and requires two groups when one would suffice.  If anyone has a better option I'd be happy to hear it.
